# Can I pass a parameter from one devops Pipeline to another? (e.g. Build and Release)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline A and Pipeline B.
Pipeline A creates an artifact "app", this pipeline has and BuildId.
I want to pass this BuildId to the next Stage as a parameter so if i start the next pipeline i can choose which artifact I want to use (e.g. App from Build 120 or from Build 210).

Is this possible, and if yes how can I do it?

I did not actually try much because I can not find any information on this in the internet. I would know how to do it in Github Actions but I have not much experience with DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **`buildId`** to identify builds of **`pipeline A`** when triggering **`Pipeline B`**, you can set the build number of **`pipeline A`** to be same as **`buildId`**. See the documentation "[**Configure run or build numbers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---

#### If **`Pipeline B`** is a YAML pipeline.

You can set **`pipeline A`** as a [**pipelines resource**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource) in **`Pipeline B`** like as below.

**`azure-pipelines.yml`** of **`Pipeline B`**.

```yaml
. . .

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PipeA  # Give a custom alias of the pipelines resource (i.e., PipeA).
    source: {name of pipeline A}

. . .
```

Then when you manually trigger a new run of **`Pipeline B`**, on the pop-up window, you can select a build from the existing builds list of **`pipeline A`**.
[image]

---

#### If **`Pipeline B`** is a classic release pipeline.

You just need add **`pipeline A`** as build type source artifact in **`Pipeline B`**.
[image]

Then when you manually trigger a new release of **`Pipeline B`**, on the pop-up window, you can select a build from the existing builds list of **`pipeline A`**.
[image]